# modal perfect construction(could have found) & real past tense(found)

Tags: grammar

Is modal perfect construction is equal to past tense when past action really happened/completed.

How this particular use of the modal perfect construction differs from the real past tense used in the second version.

It beats me how she **could have found** the secret.
It beats me how she **found** the secret.

**could have +v3** means the action was possible in past but did not happened.

Comment: could have found **implies** conditionality: She could have found out the secret [but she didn't]. It's find out, by the way, not find.

Comment: @Lambie - I disagree that the first sentence implies that she didn't find it. _She could have done it_ on its own had this meaning, but with _It beats me_ the sense is _I can't imagine how she was able to find it out_.

Comment: She could have found the secret and did find it. So, it can be either. My main point is that conditionality is implied.

Comment: To answer the core question, **what's the difference between *how she could have found* and *how she found*,** it's a difference in meaning. The second is about "how she did it," the first is about "how she *was able to* do it."

Comment: In practice, I don't think there's any difference between #1: *I don't know how you **could say** that!* and #2: *I don't know how you **could have said** that!* in most contexts (in both cases, ***You did say it***). The only *feasible* difference I see is #1 could be used if you were talking with your friend about something they would like to *communicate* to a third party in the future (and you didn't know how they should *phrase* it). But  #3: *I don't know how you **could help** me* and #4: *I don't know how you **could have helped** me* are obviously and always different.

Comment: ...so to my mind, OP's *It beats me how she could have found the secret* strongly implies *...but she **did** find it* (contrary to my expectations). To avoid that implication (i.e. - to imply she ***didn't*** find it), I'd just include an intensifier: *It beats me how she could **ever** have found the secret* (by implication, *Unsurprisingly, she didn't*).